# The difference between algebraic data types and subclasses in data Bool = False | True

Tags: haskell

I am not really familiar with Haskell but am looking through some of it. I noticed [this](https://github.com/jorendorff/talks/blob/master/algebraic-data-types/adts.md#example-bool):

```
data Bool = False | True
```

In an OO language this could be done sort of using subclasses:

```
class Bool
class False < Bool
class True < Bool
```

Wondering at a high level what the difference is between these two constructs. Wondering if a simple algebraic data type can be considered a class and its subclasses. If not, why not.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to think of sum types as typed disjoint unions. Subclasses in e.g. OO languages on the other hand share data layout, whereas in Haskell, the data constructors can be completely disjoint.

Comment: `Bool` is a type, while `False` and `True` are values. A key difference lies in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It makes more sense to think of sum types as typed disjoint unions. Subclasses in  OO languages on the other hand share data layout, whereas in Haskell, the data constructors can be completely disjoint. – [Tobias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1781434/tobias)

> Bool is a type, while False and True are values. A key difference lies in that. – [duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751851/duplode)

To see it, try `:k` at GHCi propmt:

```
~> :k Bool
Bool :: *

~> :k False
***error***
```

This is because `Bool` is a type of things, and `False` (creates) a thing. It is a (nullary) data constructor, which happens to not require any arguments:

```
x :: Bool
x = False
```

Things have types:

```
~> :t False
False :: Bool

~> :t x
x :: Bool

~> :t Bool
***error***
```